# Having issues with git access still being linked to expired Personal Access Token

Tags: git, github

Hello: Am SSH'd into another machine where I have a repo cloned. When I set up that repo it asked me to create a Personal Access Token. That Personal Access Token has since expired, and on the online github interface I went and deleted the token. However, now when I try to pull I get this:

```
(base) [my_username@login2 QIMIA]$ git pull
Password for 'https://[OLD_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]@github.com':
```

Note that where it says "[OLD_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]" on my actual terminal it has the literal personal access token there (like the whole thing). I have tried simply putting in my password to git, and tried typing out the old personal access token again. I have made a new personal access token but that hasn't changed anything (as this one seems linked to the old one).

What do I need to do to resolve this issue and be able to access my repo on this remote machine?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your repository was set up with an HTTPS URL that encodes your PAT. Confirm by running

```
git remote -v
```

You'll probably want to change the URL for that remote. One option is to update the PAT to a new, valid one. Another option is to switch to an SSH URL and authenticate with an SSH key.

In either case, you can update the URL (here we assume the remote is named `origin`) by running

```
git remote set-url origin <new-url>
```

where `<new-url>` is the new URL you wish to use, e.g. `https://[NEW_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]@github.com` or `git@github.com:someuser/somerepo.git`.